# Problems deploying a kmdf driver

Tags: deployment, driver, kmdf

I've been trying to compile and deploy the sample keyboard filter supplied by Microsoft using visual studio 2012 tools. I have the target computer setup via a serial cable (virtualbox with a serial cable, seems to be working since the setup process managed to install everything on the target computer).

The sample code compiles fine, but when I attempt to deploy it, it starts by telling me that it is deploying, takes a while, and then declares that it has failed with the following error:

error : Driver Deployment Task Failed: Default Driver Package Installation Task (possible reboot)

Anyone know what could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how to fix this problem. But i guess your settings for deployment is this in driver package's package property pages:

in the left pane of the **Package Property Pages** window,  **Configuration Properties > Driver Install > Deployment**,  you selected **Install and Verify** in the **Driver Install Options** part of the right pane.  If i hit, then you should select **Hardware ID Driver Update** and input your driver's hardware id. You can find that in your driver's inf file which is generated by vs2012.

Answer (score 0):

You may find **this** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx is useful for u, especially the **Deploying and installing the driver** part of that site.